Can I have to have a Google Docs file with Google Sheets content?
I would like to know if it is possible to have a Google Sheets document but within a Google Docs file instead of Sheets?

You can paste spreadsheet ranges and charts from Google Sheets into Google Docs (which converts them to tables and vector graphics), then use the standard Google Docs tools to position/resize/flow text around them accordingly. Upon pasting you can choose to either paste linked or unlinked - linked allows you to push any changes made in the source Sheet to the Docs copy just by clicking on 'update' on the copied element in Docs.
